# applying Aspect before spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, aspect

I have an application that use spring security and JWT for Authorization and Authentication. Here you can see my security config

```
 @Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http.headers().frameOptions().disable().and()
         .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
         .addFilter(new JwtUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(),jwtConfig,secretKey))
         .addFilterAfter(new JwtTokenVerifier(secretKey,jwtConfig),JwtUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
         .httpBasic().and()
         .authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/usercomment/**").hasAuthority("canReadUser")
         .antMatchers("/cartitem/**").hasAuthority("canReadUser")
         .antMatchers("/userorder/**").hasAuthority("canReadUser")
         .antMatchers("/userproduct/**").hasAuthority(USER_READ.name())
         .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
         .antMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll()
         .and().csrf().disable();
    }
```

I face the problem when I want to run my aspect class before spring security check the Authorization and Authentication for the controllers that I protected the URL in the configure method.

For example I need my aspect here to run before `UserOrderController` with url in configuration `/userorder/**` get checked

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class AuthorizationAndAuthenticationHanding {
    @Before(value = "execution(* com.dev.userservice.controller.UserOrderController.*(..))")
    public void  before(){
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```